# Date/Price chart for Hotels

Tags: online-resources, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

Google Flights, and probably other travel sites, has a great tool to find better prices based on dates (or date ranges).

For example, here is the Date screen from Google flights

[image]

and an example Price Graph

[image]

I'm trying to find one that does something similar for Hotels.  Enter a destination and approx dates into a search and then click on Dates/Price to find when it might be possible to get a room for cheaper.

Can anyone recommend such a service?  I'm surprised Google Travel doesn't do this, as it's such a great feature of Google Flights

Comment: While possible for a specific hotel, I don’t think this would make much sense for a whole city as there are a lot more criteria differentiating hotels than there are for flights.

Comment: @jcaron isn't that what filters are for?  I can search, filter, and sort by price, but if I want to see the price for the next day I need to re-search with new dates.  I think it's a missed opportunity, but maybe my thinking is a bit too simplistic

Comment: @lambshaanxy Well that looks like the same question (so the Dupe vote is fair) but it doesn't really have a positive answer... I guess that's my answer then though, isn't it

Comment: Hotel search sites have degraded badly over the last few years.  The prices are often without taxes, fees, surcharges and the stupid "resort fee". I've seen cases where the  final out-of-pocket price was more than double the original price. It's very inconsistent so this makes price comparisons very difficult